# Random Walk in $R^2$ vs Brownian motion in $R^2$

Tags: variance, random-walk, brownian-motion

By central limit theorem, random walk in $R^1$ converges in distribution to the Brownian motion in $R^1$.

1. For defining a 2D random walk, is there any difference between :

a) If we decompose a 2D random walk to two one dimensional random walks,

b)  If we define the random walk by a unit vector like $a=(x,y)'X =(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))'X$? $\theta$ and $X$ have uniform distribution between $[0,2\pi]$ and $[-1,1]$ and they are independent.

2. In the light of the first question, how can we prove that the 2D random walk (by 1a and/or 1b), can converge in distribution to the 2D Brownian motion?
3. In 1a, we have two variances $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ and in 1b, the variance is a matrix with zero off-diagonal. How can we have two forms of expressing variance, whereas the variance of a 2d Brownian motion is only a scalar. I think $\sigma_{2dBM}^2=4t$.

Edit: I have just found that the variance of Brownian motion in higher dimensions is in matrix form. I am still confused, why in many sources the variance is only expressed as a scalar. Only having zero off-diagonals in the matrix? More interested to see if we can decompose safely the Brownian motion/random walk to one dimensional movements, and then use central limit theorem...

Comment: How do you define 2D Brownian motion? What sort of random walk do you consider in 1a?

Comment: Terminology and definitions are not correct. A random walk converges *weakly* to the Brownian motion, not just in (finite dimensional) distribution. The 2D version of Brownian motion is called *Brownian sheet*. The invariance principle extends to the multidimensional setting. In particular, yes, a 2D version random walk converges weakly to the Brownian sheet, after normalization. What you define as $a$ is not a 2D random walk.

Comment: @Michael the case 1b is indeed not a simple random walk. But it is *some* sort of random walk, not?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus just two simple 1d random walks . not sure if it is a right way... $\sum X_i$

Comment: @Michael i edited the definition of $a$. Also i added something to the post. Appreciate to have your explanation.